# [Snowflake-ODBC]Can't get column info succesfully with SQLColumns API

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I hit a issue with snowflake-odbc driver to collect all the columns' metadata of table;

A> Download the odbc driver from
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/2.21.6/snowflake_linux_x8664_odbc-2.21.6.tgz

B> Install and config the odbc driver with doc in snowflake site:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-linux.html

I install it with unixodbc_setup.sh automatically and only updates the SF_ACCOUNT info, configure database and Warehouse values in /etc/odbc.ini

c> Test the driver with isql which works fine

```
[root@sflake1 lib]# isql -v snowflake user password

+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select * from test_vch
+-----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
| V10       | V100                                                                                                | V255                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| v10       | v100                                                                                                | v255                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| a         | b                                                                                                   | c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| aa        | bb                                                                                                  | cc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------+---------------+
SQLRowCount returns 3
3 rows fetched
SQL> quit;
```

### d> I try to get the columns with SQLCOLUMNS API;
Implement the tested C codes likes below:

```
RETCODE getColumns(SQLHSTMT hstmt, SQLCHAR* tablename)
{

    SQLRETURN rc;

    SQLCHAR szSchema[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szCatalog[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szColumnName[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szTableName[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szTypeName[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szRemarks[REM_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szColumnDefault[STR_LEN];
    SQLCHAR szIsNullable[STR_LEN];

    SQLINTEGER ColumnSize;
    SQLINTEGER BufferLength;
    SQLINTEGER CharOctetLength;
    SQLINTEGER OrdinalPosition;

    SQLSMALLINT DataType;
    SQLSMALLINT DecimalDigits;
    SQLSMALLINT NumPrecRadix;
    SQLSMALLINT Nullable;
    SQLSMALLINT SQLDataType;
    SQLSMALLINT DatetimeSubtypeCode;

    SQLLEN cbCatalog;
    SQLLEN cbSchema;
    SQLLEN cbTableName;
    SQLLEN cbColumnName;
    SQLLEN cbDataType;
    SQLLEN cbTypeName;
    SQLLEN cbColumnSize;
    SQLLEN cbBufferLength;
    SQLLEN cbDecimalDigits;
    SQLLEN cbNumPrecRadix;
    SQLLEN cbNullable;
    SQLLEN cbRemarks;
    SQLLEN cbColumnDefault;
    SQLLEN cbSQLDataType;
    SQLLEN cbDatetimeSubtypeCode;
    SQLLEN cbCharOctetLength;
    SQLLEN cbOrdinalPosition;
    SQLLEN cbIsNullable;

    SQLLEN numRecs = 0;
    SQLCHAR       SqlState[6], SQLStmt[100], Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SQLINTEGER    NativeError;
    SQLSMALLINT   i, MsgLen;

    rc = SQLColumns(hstmt, NULL, 0, (SQLCHAR*)"PUBLIC", SQL_NTS, tablename, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0);
    if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, szCatalog, STR_LEN,&cbCatalog);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, szSchema, STR_LEN, &cbSchema);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, szTableName, STR_LEN,&cbTableName);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 4, SQL_C_CHAR, szColumnName, STR_LEN, &cbColumnName);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 5, SQL_C_SSHORT, &DataType, 0, &cbDataType);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 6, SQL_C_CHAR, szTypeName, STR_LEN, &cbTypeName);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 7, SQL_C_SLONG, &ColumnSize, 0, &cbColumnSize);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 8, SQL_C_SLONG, &BufferLength, 0, &cbBufferLength);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 9, SQL_C_SSHORT, &DecimalDigits, 0, &cbDecimalDigits);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 10, SQL_C_SSHORT, &NumPrecRadix, 0, &cbNumPrecRadix);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 11, SQL_C_SSHORT, &Nullable, 0, &cbNullable);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 12, SQL_C_CHAR, szRemarks, REM_LEN, &cbRemarks);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 13, SQL_C_CHAR, szColumnDefault, STR_LEN, &cbColumnDefault);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 14, SQL_C_SSHORT, &SQLDataType, 0, &cbSQLDataType);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 15, SQL_C_SSHORT, &DatetimeSubtypeCode, 0, &cbDatetimeSubtypeCode);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 16, SQL_C_SLONG, &CharOctetLength, 0, &cbCharOctetLength);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 17, SQL_C_SLONG, &OrdinalPosition, 0, &cbOrdinalPosition);
      SQLBindCol(hstmt, 18, SQL_C_CHAR, szIsNullable, STR_LEN, &cbIsNullable);
    }

    while (SQL_SUCCESS == rc) {
       rc = SQLFetch(hstmt);
       if (rc == SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND){
          printf("SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND:All result done...");
          break;
       }
       else if(rc != SQL_SUCCESS){
         SQLGetDiagField(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, 0, SQL_DIAG_NUMBER, &numRecs, 0, 0);
         // Get the status records.
         i = 1;
         while (i <= numRecs && (rc = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, i, SqlState, &NativeError,Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {
            printf("SqlState:%s\n", SqlState);               <------ Will show errors here
            printf("NativeError:%d\n", NativeError);
            printf("Msg:%s\n", Msg);
            i++;
         }
         break;
       }

       printf("szColumnName=%s,szTypeName=%s,DataType=%d,ColumnSize=precision=%d",szColumnName,szTypeName,DataType,ColumnSize);
    }

        SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_UNBIND);
        SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE);

        return rc;
}
```

The error message shows:

```
SqlState:S1000
NativeError:6
Msg:[Snowflake][Snowflake] (6) 
 

 Assertion failure: USER_DEFINED_TYPE_type_unsupported
```

The odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini and simba.snowflake.ini are attached below:

```
[root@sflake1 log]# more /etc/odbc.ini 

[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=cy72957.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=cy72957.us-east-2.aws
database=testdbu
Warehouse=COMPUTE_WH
[root@sflake1 log]# more /etc/odbcinst.ini 
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1

[SnowflakeDSIIDriver]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
Description=Snowflake DSII
Driver=/root/snowflake/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
DriverODBCVer=03.52
SQLLevel=1
[root@sflake1 lib]# more simba.snowflake.ini
# To use this INI file, replace [INSTALLDIR] with the 
# directory the tarball was extracted to.

[Driver]
ANSIENCODING=UTF-8

## Note that this default DriverManagerEncoding of UTF-32 is for iODBC. unixODBC uses UTF-16 by default.
## If unixODBC was compiled with -DSQL_WCHART_CONVERT, then UTF-32 is the correct value.
## Execute 'odbc_config --cflags' to determine if you need UTF-32 or UTF-16 on unixODBC
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
DriverLocale=en-US
ErrorMessagesPath=/root/snowflake/snowflake_odbc/ErrorMessages/
LogLevel=0
LogNamespace=
LogPath=/root/snowflake/snowflake_odbc/log
CURLVerboseMode=false
CABundleFile=/path/to/cacert.pem

## - Uncomment the ODBCInstLib corresponding to the Driver Manager being used.
## - Note that the path to your ODBC Driver Manager must be specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (LIBPATH for AIX, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH for Darwin).
## - Note that AIX has a different format for specifying its shared libraries.

# Generic ODBCInstLib
#   iODBC
#ODBCInstLib=libiodbcinst.so.2

#   SimbaDM / unixODBC
#ODBCInstLib=libodbcinst.so

# Darwin specific ODBCInstLib
#   iODBC
#ODBCInstLib=libiodbcinst.dylib

# AIX specific ODBCInstLib
#   iODBC
#ODBCInstLib=libiodbcinst.a(libiodbcinst.so.2)

#   SimbaDM
#ODBCInstLib=libodbcinst.a(odbcinst.so)

#   unixODBC
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
CABundleFile=/root/snowflake/snowflake_odbc/lib/cacert.pem
```

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the latest version of the ODBC driver.  Per the release notes, the SQL_ATTR_METADATA_ID parameter is in 2.21.7, which affects the behavior of SQLColumns.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2020-08.html#odbc-driver-2-21-7-support-for-sql-attr-metadata-id

Comment: Thanks Mike; 
The SQL_ATTR_METADATA_ID affects the input parameters of SQLColuns but not the fetchData after searching the resultset of each columns.
I try to add the attributes too which doesn't work;

Comment: Who hit the same issue? I didn't get the root cause. Need your help. Thanks